# how to show the value of Y coordinate in every top of bar by matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

I want to add the count number in red circle, I tried to use plt.text, but I don't how to add the parameter in it

mycode:

```
path = "bogus_student_data.txt"
data = pd.read_csv(path, sep=' ')
final_grade = data['grades']
plt.hist(final_grade,bins=5, rwidth=0.8, histtype='bar', facecolor='blue',edgecolor='black')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
y = [1, 5, 3, 7, 5]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
h = ax.hist(y)
for v, i in zip(*h[:2]):
    if v > 0:
        ax.text(i + 0.25, v, str(int(v)))
fig.show()
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! however, it didn't shows the result, it appear a plot window and didn't show anything, then disappear suddenly

Comment: print(final_grade.shape)   my data is (2000,), I don't know if its shape influence the result

Comment: fig, ax =plt.subplots()
h = ax.hist(final_grade,bins=5, rwidth=0.8, histtype='bar', facecolor='blue',edgecolor='black')

'''
for v, i in zip(*h[:2]):
    if v > 0:
        ax.text(i + 0.25, v, str(int(v)))

fig.show()

Comment: Tested it in both jupyter and console and works fine. Do you got any errors?